# What can a second year computer undergrad do which might be considered worthwhile in the future?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, project

Besides taking classes I mean. I want to make myself stand out from the crowd. I am very good at building logic/algorithms. Like I can implement any problem in C. But I don't know how to harness it! Like what to code!?!

All I have made upto this point is games that too in C's console, using ASCII and character arrays. Snake, Sudoku (making a puzzle and solving too), rip-off of Mario Bros., tictactoe with AI. But making games won't get me anywhere.

I was wondering if I could get suggestions from you guys?

I know C++/C and a little Java. I have just got started with data structures. So, it would be great if it would be relevant to data structures. I know about most trees and types of data structures. Thanks a lot for your help.
I know it's off topic but I have nowhere else to turn to.

Comment: This is opinion based, so doesn't really belong here. I wonder though : why do you think coding games doesn't get you anywhere? It doesn't really matter what the subject of your next project is, as long as you're trying out new stuff, you're improving. And you're always adding to a portfolio that will be useful to prove that you have been coding by yourself for a while.  If I were you, I would start experimenting with different languages.

Comment: It is off-topic, and will likely be closed shortly. You'd be surprised how far making games will get you. Regardless, I would recommend finding yourself an open-source project that interests you, and contributing to it. You can find many in need of contribution on GitHub, and this is something that you can point to, alongside your portfolio, when potential employers ask what you've been up to.

Comment: To be honest I have no idea that what help can these little games be of. And yes, "experimenting with different languages" is exactly what I am doing. Learning Java. But I was hoping to do something more fun :)

Comment: Join an open source project. The RadWind (radmind for windows, PC-Radmind) project needs C coders...

Comment: Apply for a year in industry programme. This if for example what our institute offers: http://www.tgac.ac.uk/opportunities/

Comment: You need to experiment in a lot of different fields to find out what you really want to do. Games are not bad, especially as they can become quite complex, potentially covering all fields from handling large amounts of data, graphics, physics, network communication, etc.

Comment: Pretend as though you have just graduated and look at the job listings for your ideal job. Look at the skills they need. Think up a quick, simple project that enables you to learn/demonstrate these skills. By the time you graduate you will stand out from the crowd.

Comment: This could easily be moved to stack overflow programmers.

Answer (score 4):

1. Pay attention in your finite automata classes.  Learning the basis of all languages makes "knowing" a language irrelevant.
2. If your school offers it, take some business computer systems classes.
3. Try to get some project management experience under your belt.  This could be done by doing work for charity or an internship for a prof.
4. Of course there is always open source projects as well.
5. Get a job.  I was working for a small development shop as a second year student.
6. Open your own company, and start doing some mobile apps.  The sky is the limit.

Comment: Sir, can you be specific as to what kind of job?

Comment: I worked doing project planning software for a small engineering firm.  The firm mostly served the oil industry.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have long term impact, you can do one of two things:

- Be a genius, and invent a new gizmo everybody needs. [Extra points].
- Build a foundation for something. Add to it cleanly, continuously. Eventually it will have enough mass to have an impact.